# web2py select distinct values

Tags: select, web2py, distinct-values

I have a table like col1, col2, col3, col4, col5. I want to select distinct values of col3 and my query looks like below:

```
db().select(db.table.col1, db.table.col3, distinct=db.table.col3)
```

The query fails.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow :) please familiraize yourself with how to ask a good question. Please also use formatting in your questions. Provide us more detailed info of what does failes means

Answer (score 2):

Except maybe when using postgresql as mentioned by @Anthony, for all other relational databases (afaik) distinct cannot be applied to individual fields part of the resultset, other then  all fields. Web2py relects this in the parameter use. This can be set to True, or to all fields requested. As is in the book, from which i quoted the relevant for your convenience.

If you use sqlite use the `groupby` as mentioned by Anthony and apply aggregates for example: `db().select(db.table.col1.max(), db.table.col3.max(), groupby=db.table.col3)`

Hope this helps.

From the web2py manual, [aggregates section](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#orderby--groupby--limitby--distinct--having-orderby_on_limitby-left-cache):

> distinct
>
> With the argument distinct=True, you can specify that you only want to select distinct records. This has the same effect as grouping using all specified fields except that it does not require sorting. When using distinct it is important not to select ALL fields, and in particular not to select the "id" field, else all records will always be distinct.
>
> Here is an example:

```
>>> for row in db().select(db.person.name, distinct=True):
        print row.name
```

> Alex
> Bob
> Carl
> Notice that distinct can also be an expression for example:

```
>>> for row in db().select(db.person.name,distinct=db.person.name):
    print row.name
```

> Alex
> Bob
> Carl

Answer (score 0):

If you set `distinct` to an expression (such as a Field object), it results in the `DISTINCT ON` SQL statement, which I believe is not supported in SQLite. It should work in PostgreSQL, though. As an alternative, you can try:

```
db().select(db.table.col1, db.table.col3, groupby=db.table.col3)
```

Either way, though, you might be missing some distinct values of `col1`, as you are not doing any aggregation.